# How can I pass getJSON results into an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to populate a from with the data from the last record in my db with $.getJSON.
The GET returns the JSON but I can't get the data to populate the fields. I'm a complete neewb to much of this.

```
$.getJSON("loadloads.php", function (data) {
    document.getElementById("LoadNumber").innerHTML = data.LoadNumber
});
```

this is the JSON returned, copied from firebug.

```
[{
    "value": {
        "LoadNumber": "227303",
        "OrderDate": "2013-04-09",
        "ShipDate": "2013-04-09",
        "ShipTime": "12:00:00",
        "DeliveryDate": "2013-04-10",
        "DeliveryTime": null,
        "PurchaseOrderNumber": "0002323803",
        "CustomerId": "200540",
        "Rate": "801.08",
        "EmployeeId1": "1",
        "EmployeeId2": "1",
        "CarrierId": "201383",
        "CarrierRate": "700",
        "Tarp": "NO",
        "Status": "Dispatched",
        "Notes": "Pls check in as an All Points Inc. carrier.  V-boards reg.  Shipper tracking we need Proof of delivery faxed or called in A.S.A.P (within 24 hours)  Need printed name of person signing for load.  Must haul 48K min.",
        "LoadTypeId": "1",
        "LoadType": "Flatbed",
        "BillingNotes": "608.48 + 192.60",
        "InvoiceDate": null,
        "PayDate": null,
        "DestinationNext": null,
        "Covered": "0",
        "CompanyName": "GAF Materials Corp.",
        "CarrierName": "Daniel Zamora",
        "FN1": "Craig",
        "FN2": "Craig"
    }
}]
```

this is the input box

```
<label for="LoadNumber">Load Number :
    <input type="text" size="12" id="LoadNumber" Name="LoadNumber" tabindex="-1" />
</label>
```

Comment: When you were writing your question, there was this handy **How to Format** box to the right. Well worth a read. There was also a **[?]** button above the text area, and a preview area underneath. The more legible the question, the better your odds are of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON defines an array which has one entry, which is an object, which has one property, `value`, which is an object with a bunch of properties, of which `LoadNumber` is one. Separately, since `LoadNumber` is an `input` element, you'd use `.value` rather than `.innerHTML`.

So instead of

```
document.getElementById("LoadNumber").innerHTML = data.LoadNumber
```

It should be:

```
document.getElementById("LoadNumber").value = data[0].value.LoadNumber;
```

(The semicolon isn't absolutely necessary, but I strongly recommend not relying on the Horror of Semicolon Insertion.)

`data` refers to the array as a whole, so `[0]` gives us the first entry, then `.value` gives us the `value` property of that object, and `.LoadNumber` gives us the `LoadNumber` property of *that* object. More verbosely:

```
var firstEntry = data[0];
var valueObject = firstEntry.value;
document.getElementById("LoadNumber").value = valueObject.LoadNumber;
```

Of course, since you're using jQuery, you could use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) instead:

```
$("#LoadNumber").val(data[0].value.LoadNumber);
```

Comment: actually since LoadNumber is an input wouldn't it be more prudent to use .val()?

Comment: @scrappedcola: Thanks, I missed that it was an `input`.

Comment: the .val() solved it. I tried the other and it didn't work. thank you.